# Как увидеть результат запуска контейнера?

Tags: docker

Я на основе образа ubuntu собрал контейнер. его суть в том, что устанавливается и запускается консольный монитор ресурсов ОС.

Вот докерфайл:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y htop
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "export TERM=xterm && /usr/bin/htop"]
```

Контейнер собрался успешно, но после запуска я не могу увидеть результат работы. дело в том, что после запуска команды:

```
docker run ubuntu-htop
```

ничего не происходит. Я ожидаю, что откроется отдельное окно с выводом инофрмации о системных ресурсах ОС, но этого не происходит.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём суть проблемы и как её решить.

Моя ОС linux mint 17

Comment: `$ docker -it run ...`. но никакого «отдельного окна», естественно, не появится. ввод/вывод будет привязан к тому эмулятору терминала, где вы и запускаете процесс docker.

Answer (score 0):

Если имя контейнера `ubuntu-htop` то подключиться к стандартному вводу/выводу контейнера можно выполнив команду:

```
docker attach ubuntu-htop
```

Если нажать `CTRL+c` то контейнер получит сигнал SIGTERM и будет остановлен. Для того, чтоб можно было отсоединится от контейнера по `CTRL+c`, не останавливая его, нужно подсоединяться к контейнеру с ключом `--sig-proxy=false`:

```
docker attach --sig-proxy=false ubuntu-htop
```

Для того, что бы просто просмотреть вывод запущенной в контейнере программы:

```
docker logs ubuntu-htop
```

Если контейнер сейчас не исполняется, то эта команда выведет логи предыдущего запуска. Это позволяет увидеть ошибку если предыдущий запуск не был успешным.

А если нужно просто мониторить вывод в *stdout/stderr* приложения в контейнере:

```
docker logs -f ubuntu-htop
```

*Вместо имени контейнера во всех случаях можно использовать его идентификатор.*